# Visual Studio 2019 16.8.0 uninstalled latest 3.1 SDK and global.json does not work anymore

Tags: .net, .net-core, sdk

we use the global.json to specify the SDK version for our projects:

```
{
    "sdk": {
    "version": "3.1.200",
    "rollForward": "latestFeature"
    }
}
```

I had installed VS2019 16.7.6 and the following SDKs:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>dotnet --list-sdks
2.1.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.504 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.807 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.808 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.809 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.810 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.811 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
3.1.109 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
3.1.403 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

Today I upgraded to VS2019 16.8.0 and now the following SDKs are installed:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>dotnet --list-sdks
2.1.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.504 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.807 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.808 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.809 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.810 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.811 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
3.1.109 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
5.0.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

So the update removed the SDK 3.1.403 and as a result I now get a compile error, because the global.json requests 3.1.200 (with rollForward to latest feature)

So my question is:

- Why did the update to VS 16.8.0 uninstall the SDK 3.1.403?
- Why is SDK 3.1.109 still there?
- Is there an overview showing which VS version comes with which SDK?

edit
I found that these sites give an overview of which SDK version came with which VS Update

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.1

Answer (score 3):

I just dealt with the same problem (also affects .NET Core 2.1 SDKs). I just installed the latest 3.1 SDK and 2.1 SDK, then updated my global.json files to use those versions. Everything worked fine after that

Comment: Well, I installed the latest .Net Core 3.1 SDK from here https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks
and now everything works fine again.
Still I think this is weird behavior of the VS Updates!